# How to call a function which defined in external script in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs.

I  am trying to add a external script and trying to use a function which defined inside that script.

Script is

```
<script src="https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/js/sagepay.js"></script>

    <script>
      document.querySelector('[type=submit]').addEventListener(
        'click',
        function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); // to prevent form submission
          sagepayOwnForm({
            merchantSessionKey: '5528D329-A83B-435F-B6A7-E38A2BC60DC9',
          }).tokeniseCardDetails({
            cardDetails: {
              cardholderName: document.querySelector(
                '[data-card-details="cardholder-name"]'
              ).value,
              cardNumber: document.querySelector(
                '[data-card-details="card-number"]'
              ).value,
              expiryDate: document.querySelector(
                '[data-card-details="expiry-date"]'
              ).value,
              securityCode: document.querySelector(
                '[data-card-details="security-code"]'
              ).value,
            },
            onTokenised: function (result) {
              if (result.success) {
                document.querySelector('[name="card-identifier"]').value =
                  result.cardIdentifier;
                document.querySelector('form').submit();
              } else {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
              }
            },
          });
        },
        false
      );
    </script>
```

I tried with `useScript`. When user click the submit button the script will loaded and should call
`sagepayOwnForm` ( this is a defined in their script.js)

I create a `useScript`

```
export const useScript = (url: string) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');

        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;
        // script.on

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [url]);
};
```

I don't know how to use this. I want to know How can I call their function.

Can anyone help me.